# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'value.getvalue') "replace <View /> by animated <Animated.View>"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have started `react-native` recently and have been working on this app for the past few days and everything was going well. Then I re-wrote this in class(Code snippet bellow) and suddenly I started getting an error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'value.getvalue) "replace <View />  by animated <Animated.View />".even I changed the <View />  to <Animated.View>..still I am getting this error where I mapped the Array. before using class I was using `useState()` and 'useEffect()' to rendering time.please help to fix it.Thank you

`code snippet`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Image,StyleSheet,SafeAreaView,ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import {Text,View,Button,TextField,StackAggregator,Colors,TabBar} from 'react-native-ui-lib';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component{
 
  constructor({route,navigation}){
    super();
    this.setTime = [];
    this.url = "https://xyz.zxy?latitude=19.2881825&longitude=72.8568436";
    this.state ={IsLoading:true};
      fetch(this.url)
      .then(response => response.json() )
      .then(datas => {
        var tdata = datas['data'][0];
        console.log(tdata);
        var timings = tdata['timings'];
        this.setTime.push(timings['Mon']);
        this.setTime.push(timings['Tue']);
        this.setTime.push(timings['Wed']);
        this.setTime.push(timings['Thu']);
        this.setTime.push(timings['Fri']);
        this.setTime.push(timings['Sat']);
        this.setTime.push(timings['Sun']);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
      .finally(() => this.setState({IsLoading:false}));
  }
  render(){
    return (  
      <SafeAreaView style={homestyles.container}>
        <ScrollView bg-dark80 keyboardShouldPersis1tTaps={'handled'} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
        <Animated.View>
        <StackAggregator
            collapsed={true}
            contentContainerStyle={{width:wp('91%'),height:hp('18%'),backgroundColor:"#bd9a3e"}} 
            itemBorderRadius={10}
          >
          {
            this.setTime.map((Time,key)=>(
              <Animated.View>
                <Animated.View style={homestyles.timecrd_ctr}> 
                  <Image style={homestyles.bgImage} source={require('./assets/timecard.png')} resizeMode='cover' />
                  <Text style={homestyles.crdtm_text}>{Time}</Text>
                </Animated.View>
              </Animated.View>
            ))
          }
          </StackAggregator>
          </Animated.View>
          </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
    const homestyles = StyleSheet.create({
    timecrd_ctr:{
      paddingLeft:wp('2.5%'),
      paddingBottom:hp('2.5%'),
      paddingTop:hp('2.5%'),
      paddingRight:wp('2.5%'),
    },
    crdtime_card:{
        backgroundColor:'black',
    },
    crdtm_text:{
        color:'white',
        fontSize: 30,
    },
    container:{
        flex:1,
        paddingTop:hp('2.5%'),
        backgroundColor:"#001D25",
    },
    bgImage:{
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      right: 0,
      width:wp('92%'),
      height:hp('20%'),
      transform:[{scaleX: -1}],
    },      
});
```

[image]

Comment: Remove `this.` in this line:  `<Text style={homestyles.crdtm_text}>{this.Time}</Text>` so it becomes  `<Text style={homestyles.crdtm_text}>{Time}</Text>`

Comment: sorry that my my code mistake but it's not related to The error mentioned sir